# 'Npgsql' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions'

Tags: npgsql

Please help how to solve this?

> 'Npgsql' already has a dependency defined for
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions':

[image: 'Npgsql' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions']

I've already installed package System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions -Version 4.4.0 
Install-Package System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions -Version 4.4.0

even after that I am unable to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please post errors and any relevant code as text.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm seeing the same thing (with Npgsql 3.2.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh the nupkg dll by downloading and copying it manually.

- Go to: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/
- Click: Manual download option.
- Open the nupkg downloaded file with a file extraction program like WinZip or WinRar.
- Search for the dll in the path lib\net45\Npgsql.dll and copy.